# How to Create a Date Input Field

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

How can I create an apex input with data type date?

I tried using `showDatePicker` but it has an error:

> value for `<apex:inputField>` is not a dynamic binding.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways in which you can achieve this.

If you want to mimic datepicker which is seen in salesforce UI, the simplest one is as suggested by @Boris in his answer.

The other ways include:

1. Use HTML input tag with attribute as type="date"

   `<input type="date" name="bday">`
2. Use HTML input tag and any javascript library like jQuery, ExtJs etc. The below example is for jQuery. You can use jQuery datepicker() function to turn a text box into datepicker.

   `<input type="text" id="datepicker">`

   `<script>
       $(function(){
         $("#datepicker" ).datepicker();
       });
    </script>`
3. Use salesforce apex:inputText tag and any javascript library like jQuery, ExtJs.

   ```
   <apex:inputtext id="datePicker" onclick="openDatePicker()"/>
      <script>
       var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
       function openDatePicker(){                                
           var dtpckr= document.getElementById('{!$Component.datePicker}');
           j$(dtpckr).datepicker();
       }
      </script>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question correctly (input field date), you're referring to VisualForce.

You can create a temporary instance of an sObject which has a date field, for an example Opportunity which has a field CloseDate.

So in your controller add:

`public Opportunity oppty {get; set;}`

Then inside your constructor or init method create a new instance:

`oppty = new Opportunity();`

Finally in your VisualForce page you can use it as:

`<apex:inputField value="{!oppty.CloseDate}" />`

Then whatever you do in your controller, you can always reference the value in `oppty.CloseDate`.

This is one of the quickest but not cleanest solutions.

Comment: I am not using Opportunity object but have to use it in order to enable <apex:inputField> .This seem little dirty but solve the issue instead of waiting this feature to be available by salesforce.